# Why doesn't malloc work in my own implementation of BST tree

Tags: c, algorithm, malloc, binary-search-tree

This is the node definition:

```
typedef struct drzewo BST;
struct drzewo  {
   int key;
   BST *left;
   BST *right;
   BST *p;
};
```

and I am trying to write add function:

```
BST *add(  BST *root, int val)
{
   BST  *x = root;
   BST *nowe =(BST*)malloc(sizeof(BST));


   nowe->key = val;
   nowe->left=nowe->right=nowe->p=NULL;
   ...
}
```

but it appears that malloc is resulting in segmentation fault, when root=NULL, or other error (writing on windows). Why is that so?

Comment: The error is in the `...`. Also, don't cast the result of `malloc()`. Also also, use a debugger.

Comment: left, right understandable.. but what is p for?

Comment: ok, this code is correct, but i tried to debug it with printf, fflush and it pointed malloc, i'm writing under dev-c++. But can be the reason that I put the majority of code inside .h files (bad practice)?

Comment: If the error only happens when root==null then most probably the error happens in any code after the `...` which accesses the `x` -- could you include more code?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that, within the `...` you have an assignment to (or read from) `x->left` or `x->right`, to facilitate linking your newly-allocated node into the tree. If root is NULL, this should fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (if your system is Linux) or a debugger to debug your issues.

Learn to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux).